# Identify unique tcp connetion to a Linux server

Tags: networking, firewall

I'm in the planning stages of migrating an application from one Linux server to a new Linux server.  The new server will have a different IP address and a different hostname.

One of the items on my list is to identify the required firewall rules for the new server.  I'd like to find a way to identify all the unique connections to the old server so I can provide that to our network team so they can create new rules for the new server accordingly.

I've tried running tcpdump over a period of time but there is just way too much information in the collected file to comb through.  Is there a similar tool I could run that would give me the information I need?  I looked into netstat but that seems to just give moment-in-time connections which could be missed if the connections were very transient.

Comment: Check what is listen on the old machine, check particular daemon and decide to add or not to firewall rules.

Comment: You can check with ss -natp | grep -i list

Comment: You can also use the `netstat`, which is basically an older version of `ss` which another user already adviced you. You will need the `net-tools` to use it tho

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the remote machines connecting to your server?  If so, you could use `iptables` to log new connections.

e.g. if your server listened on port 12345 then you could do

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12345 -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-New-app: " --log-level 4
```

This will create log messages such as

```
IPTables-New-app: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:01:23:45:67:89:ab:cd:ef:01:23:45:67:89 SRC=10.20.30.40 DST=100.200.300.400 LEN=52 TOS=0x0A PREC=0x20 TTL=116 ID=32405 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=63669 DPT=12345 WINDOW=200 RES=0x00 CWR ECE SYN URGP=0
```

We can see the source address in there.

To avoid performance impact this limits the number of log lines generated; you can adjust that to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Save the TCP dump in a file and use `grep` for a first selection. You're interested in what comes in so

```
grep ' > ronsard.home`
```

would be a good first selection (replace `ronsard.home` with your on system).

Next, you're not interested in when it happened, so remove the time stamp. also, the flags are mostly irrelevant for you. Also, the ephemeral port numbers (5 digits) are not interesting. So `sed` will help you there:

```
sed 's/.*IP //;s/Flags.*//;s/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]//g''
```

Finaly, you pipe it through

```
sort -u
```

Now you have probably the interesting part of the sessions and it should not be such a insurmountable quantity of data anymore.

There are security aspects to this method. You should determine from the application point of view what are the acceptable connections. Not from what is currently done.  The two examples that show that allowing measured sessions does not guarantee the right firewall rules are:

- if a hacker is currently hacking your old system, you will create firewall rules that allow him to access the new system too.
- If you've measured a day. you may miss those who use the application once a week.